# Soma de elementos da lista

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Tenho uma base de dados que me retorna essa lista:

[[local; cliente; contrato; lote; cabecas], [local; cliente; contrato; lote; cabecas], [local; cliente; contrato; lote; cabecas], [local; cliente; contrato; lote; cabecas]...]

Preciso retornar a soma de todos os dados das "colunas" cabeças, onde o cliente = "Nelson".
Mas não estou conseguindo realizar o calculo, e nem retornar a variável.
Segue o código abaixo:

```dart
void main() => runApp(TableLayout());

class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [];
  late int cab;
  late List cablista = [];

  Future loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/dados.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable =
        CsvToListConverter(fieldDelimiter: ";").convert(myData);

    _data = csvTable.where((x) => x[1] == "Nelson").toList();
  }

  Future calccabecas() async {
    cablista = _data.elementAt(3).toList();
    cab = cablista.elementAt(3).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Titulo",
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Future.wait([
                    loadAsset(),
                    calccabecas(),
                  ]).then((_) {
                    setState(() {});
                  });
                }),
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              title: const Text("Table Layout and CSV"),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Column(children: [
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
                Card(child: Text("Lotes: ")),
                Card(child: Text("Contratos: ")),
                Card(child: Text("Cabeças: " + cab)),
              ]),
              Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text("Curral: " + _data[index][0]),
                              Text("Pecuarista: " + _data[index][1]),
                              Text("Contrato: ${_data[index][2]}"),
                              Text("Lote: ${_data[index][3]}"),
                              Text("Cabeças: ${_data[index][4]}")
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa ! Veja se isso resolve para você:
No caso é criada uma lista e eu retorno com o where uma sublista e depois faço a soma dos valores.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> lista = [];

lista.add({'nome': 'nelson', 'dado':1});
lista.add({'nome': 'nelson', 'dado':2});
lista.add({'nome': 'joao', 'dado':2});
lista.add({'nome': 'ana', 'dado':2});

final listQtd = [...lista.where((e) => e['nome'] == 'nelson')];

int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< listQtd.length; i++){
  total += listQtd[i]['dado'] as int;
}

print ('$total'); /// vai imprimir 3
```